# Asserting that a method is called exactly one time

Tags: tdd, mocking, rhino-mocks, assertions

I want to assert that a method is called exactly one time. I'm using RhinoMocks 3.5.

Here's what I thought would work:

```cs
[Test]
public void just_once()
{
    var key = "id_of_something";

    var source = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomeDataSource>();
    source.Expect(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key))
        .Return(new Something())
        .Repeat.Once();

    var client = new Client(soure);

    // the first call I expect the client to use the source
    client.GetMeMyThing(key);

    // the second call the result should be cached
    // and source is not used
    client.GetMeMyThing(key);
}
```

I want this test to fail if the second invocation of `GetMeMyThing()` calls `source.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources()`.

Comment: The only things wrong with the above are the use of GenerateStub instead of GenerateMock and missing this last line: client.VerifyAllExpectations();

Comment: ...I have edited the accepted answer...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's how I'd verify a method is called once.

```cs
[Test]
public void just_once()
{
    // Arrange (Important to GenerateMock not GenerateStub)
    var a = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISomeDataSource>();
    a.Expect(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources()).Return(new Something()).Repeat.Once();

    // Act
    // First invocation should call GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources
    a.GetMeMyThing();

    // Second invocation should return cached result
    a.GetMeMyThing();

    // Assert
    a.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Comment: +1 for using 'using (mocks.Record()) { .. } It increases readability a lot.

Comment: -1 This does not work. It will not throw an exception if GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources is called more than once.

Comment: I am quite sure this was working at the time I wrote this 2 years ago. I'll update the post to include the new way to do it.

Comment: However, the second a.Expect(...) should be a.Stub(...) or the call to a.VerifyAllExpectations() will fail if x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key) is only called once.

Comment: And the remaining a.Expect(...).Return(...) needs to be a.Expect(...).Return(...).Repeat.Once().

Comment: I've changed the second `.Expect` to a `.Stub` - experiementation showed that the `a.VerifyAllExpectatons()` fails otherwise.

Comment: This answer while accepted is more complicated that it needs to be, I will edit out the unnecessary stub

Answer (score 16):

I have been using the AssertWasCalled extension to get around this problem.  This is the best I could find/come up with but it would be better if I didn't have to specify the call twice.

```
    [Test]
    public void just_once()
    {
        var key = "id_of_something";

        var source = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomeDataSource>();

        // set a positive expectation
        source.Expect(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key))
            .Return(new Something())
            .Repeat.Once();

        var client = new Client(soure);
        client.GetMeMyThing(key);
        client.GetMeMyThing(key);

        source.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key),
                               x => x.Repeat.Once());
        source.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the only answer that worked for me. One difference for me was that to avoid internal exceptions (nullref) & ensure I got a nice Rhino Expectation exception instead, I had to Repeat.Twice() to get past the "fail" case. That's why this solution is good, this doesn't matter, the AssertWasCalled defines exactly what's required

Comment: What does the `Excpect` do? I don't think `VerifyAllExpectations` works on a Stub, it only works on a Mock. But even if it would work, what's the use? Your `AssertWasCalled` contains all the assertions it needs. I would change the `Expect` to `Stub` and ditch the `Repeat.Once`, and also remove the `VerifyAllExpectations`.

Comment: If you change the .GenerateStub to .GenerateMock you can drop the AssertWasCalled and rely on the VerifyAllExpectations - see accepted answer for simplest solution - I edited it.

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in [this bit](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#Thedifferencebetweenstubsandmocks) from the Rhino Mocks 3.5 Documentation (quoted below).  Looks like you need to mock the class, not stub it, for it to work the way you expect.

> The difference between stubs and mocks
>
> ...
>
> A mock is an object that we can set
>   expectations on, and which will verify
>   that the expected actions have indeed
>   occurred. A stub is an object that you
>   use in order to pass to the code under
>   test. You can setup expectations on
>   it, so it would act in certain ways,
>   but those expectations will never be
>   verified. A stub's properties will
>   automatically behave like normal
>   properties, and you can't set
>   expectations on them.
>
> If you want to verify the behavior of
>   the code under test, you will use a
>   mock with the appropriate expectation,
>   and verify that. If you want just to
>   pass a value that may need to act in a
>   certain way, but isn't the focus of
>   this test, you will use a stub.
>
> IMPORTANT: A stub will never cause a
>   test to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I just did (as recommended by [Ray Houston](http://twitter.com/rayhouston/statuses/1003171744)). I would still appreciate a more elegant solution...

```
[Test]
public void just_once()
{
    var key = "id_of_something";

    var source = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomeDataSource>();

    // set a positive expectation
    source.Expect(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key))
        .Return(new Something())
        .Repeat.Once();

    var client = new Client(soure);

    client.GetMeMyThing(key);

    // set a negative expectation
    source.Expect(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key))
        .Return(new Something())
        .Repeat.Never();

    client.GetMeMyThing(key);
}
```

Comment: This would only work if your calling code was at a high enough level that you had access to the repeated method. In my case, I'm calling into 1 method where 2 calls are made inside that method, so I can't repeat the call inside the test body. I still tried it anyway, but the Never() just overrides the Once and I just get Expect 1 got 0

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a delegate to WhenCalled to count calls:

```
...
uint callCount = 0;
source.Expect(x => x.GetSomethingThatTakesALotOfResources(key))
    .Return(new Something())
    .WhenCalled((y) => { callCount++; });
...
Assert.AreEqual(1, callCount);
```

Also, you should use a mock not a stub, and verify expectations on the mock too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create strict mock, if you want to ensure that a method is called only once.

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IMustOnlyBeCalledOnce>();
mock.Expect(a => a.Process()).Repeat.Once();
var helloWorld= new HelloWorld(mock);

helloworld.Process()

mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Answer (score -1):

Having a feature called "Exactly" would be handy to write tests on code that might otherwise get into an infinite loop.  I would love to write a test such that the second call to a method would raise an exception.

Some libraries for python allow you to sequence expectations, so the first returns false and the second raises an exception.

Rhino won't do that.  A partial mock with .Once will intercept the first call, and the rest will be passed on to the original method.  So that sucks, but it's true.

You'll have to create a hand-mock.  Derive a "testable" class, and give it the ability to raise after the first call.